# R: Point On Graph Does Not Appear in Data

Tags: r, plot, 3d, plotly, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language. I defined a function, evaluated this function at different points and created a graph of this function:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)

#create grid and evaluate function
input_1 <- seq(0,100,1)
input_2 <- seq(0,100,1)
input_3 <- seq(0,100,1)
input_4 <- seq(0,100,1)

my_grid <- data.frame(input_1, input_2, input_3, input_4)
my_grid$final_value = sin(input_1) + cos(input_2) + input_3 + input_4

plot_ly() %>% 
        add_trace(data = my_grid,  x=my_grid$input_1, y=my_grid$input_2, z=my_grid$input_3, type='mesh3d') %>%
        add_surface(
                z = my_grid %>% as.matrix(),
                surfacecolor = my_grid,
                cauto=F,
                cmax=max(my_grid$final_value),
                cmin=min(my_grid$final_value)
        )
```

[image]

**Problem:** In this above plot, I was under the impression that `x = input_1, y = input_2, z = input_3` and the color of the plot is according to "final_value". I have highlighted a point on the graph of (4,100, 200.356) . But if you were to look at the data used to create this plot (`"my_grid"`), there is no such point in the data.

**Question:** Can someone please explain this? Or am I misunderstanding this? Is it possible to alter the "hover text" so that for any point on this plot, it clearly displays the values of "input_1, input_2, input_3 and final_value"?  Can someone please help me clarify this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's `my_grid %>% tail()` and see what happens,

```
    input_1 input_2 input_3 input_4 final_value
96       95      95      95      95    191.4134
97       96      96      96      96    192.8032
98       97      97      97      97    193.4545
99       98      98      98      98    194.6073
100      99      99      99      99    197.0406
101     100     100     100     100    200.3560
```

The last `observation` is `(100,4,200.3560)`, so it does exist.

Comment: thank you for your reply! But I don't see the number "4"?

Comment: I guess I was a bit fast! At this point I'm a bit clueless to be honest. I cant even reproduce https://plotly.com/r/3d-mesh/ using your `data`. I'll tap out for now!

Comment: But it seems that with you plot, the x-axis are normalized. But in the link above, which are similar, are not.

Comment: Yeah - I thought I had the answer... Sorry about that! When you find a solution, please post the answer! Im rather curious! :-)